# Через несколько секунд после загрузки сайта исчезает скролл

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть сайт на вордпрессе:
https://evroflag.by/
Через несколько секунд после загрузки сайта, исчезает возможность скроллинга. Появляется она обратно после клика по любому месту сайта.
Причина, что в body, каким то образом прописывается правило overflow: hidden;
Как это исправить? Почему оно прописывается.
Пытался в css документе прописать overflow: auto !important;, но не помогает.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл такое решение. Переписать css :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Правильное решение - выяснить, кто и зачем прописывает это в `<body>` и убить заразу. А переопределять стилями - это уже костыль.